# How to add id to action in HTML.form

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp

I have form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/user/${id}">
    <input type="text" value="${id}" placeholder="Input Id">
    <button>Get User</button>
</form>
```

I need to add input data to URI, like this /user/23, where 23 in inputed data.

Comment: Are you using a server-side language?  If so, which?  If browser-side, where does the value come from?

Comment: I'm using JSP and Java.

Comment: OK.  Not my area, but good that you added a tag so that people skilled in that area can help.  I put in a request for a jsp tag, too.

Answer (score 3):

In JSP, you can output HTML in 2 ways

```
<form method="POST" action="/user/<%=id%>">
    <input type="text" value="<%=id%>" placeholder="Input Id">
    <button>Get User</button>
</form>
```

OR

```
<%
out.println("<form method=\"POST\" action=\"/user/"+id+"\">");
out.println("<input type=\"text\" value=\""+id+"\" placeholder=\"Input Id\">");
out.println("<button>Get User</button>");
out.println("</form>");
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to have /user/23 as your URI? If you don't, you can use "/user/" as your action.

```
<form method="POST" action="/user">
    <input type="text" name="user_id" placeholder="Input Id">
    <button>Get User</button>
</form>
```

Then you can get/handle the proper id. Something like:

```
<%= request.getParameter("user_id")%>
```

Comment: Yes, I need /user/23 as URI. 23 is user ID.

Comment: Where will you use it?

Comment: On my controller. I'm using Spring MVC.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say. In your controller, you can retrieve the the id, getting the value of the textinput. You don't need to put the id on your URI. Just use "/user" to call your controller

Comment: `/user/23/` isn't a bad format... it's actually part of a RESTful implementation.